# jQuery MultiSelect - Does it work with IE9 (workaround)?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, multi-select

I have a had a couple of instances that jQuery.Multiselect will not render correctly in IE9?  It could my my own installation but this is what is getting rendered (Chrome and Mozilla work fine):

Demo page and docs links:
http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/multiSelect/demo/

http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/04/jquery-multiselect/

Related Case:
[Multiselect list will not drop down in IE9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972327/multiselect-list-will-not-drop-down-in-ie9)
IE9:

Just to be clear, THE ASK is a work around using the same control

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Exactly which plugin are you using? Because the demo pages for [this one](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/) and [this one](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/) seem to work on IE9.

Comment: Did you get any errors, JQuery errors, or otherwise, when running the page? What did your developer tools tell you?

Comment: Maybe you got Javascript disabled in this browser?

Comment: @GolezTrol: Javascript is definitely enabled.

Comment: I confirm, this doesn't render correctly in IE9. Damn, what a crap of a browser is this IE. Looking forward to the day this crap of a browser is wiped out of existence from the planet Earth.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Amen! Thanks for verifying!

Comment: @Jacquo, I really don't know what you expect from this question. Maybe you should contact the team that wrote the plugin and ask them to test their own s..t under IE. Open a ticket or something.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Hi, yes indeed I have opened a ticket.  My premis is to simply reach out and see if anybody has encountered this issue and had a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the bgiframe plugin, as Brandon stated.  I have updated the dependency, reorganized the image files into a folder, and pushed a new version (1.2.3).  I recommend downloading it from the project page: http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/04/jquery-multiselect/

Alternatively, here is the direct link to the ZIP: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/multiSelect/jquery.multiSelect-1.2.3.zip

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I can get the demo (http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/multiSelect/demo/) to come up correctly in IE9 but the zip doesn't come up correctly (same as previous output).  What files do I need, which ones were updated?  Thx!

Comment: Sorry about that...it was the jquery.bgiframe.min.js file that didn't get packed correctly in the ZIP.  I've updated it, so clear your browser's cache and download it again.  If you'd rather get the new version directly, it's here (should be v2.1.3-pre): http://labs.abeautifulsite.dev/projects/js/jquery/multiSelect/jquery.bgiframe.min.js

Answer (score 2):

In short, the answer is no, it does not work with IE9 assuming the demo provided makes proper use of the library. I confirmed, via the console, that an exception is preventing further execution of some code which is most likely the cause of this.

The exception states:

```
SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5) 
jquery.bgiframe.min.js, line 10 character 978
```

Comment: Thanks for checking this out!