# Multiselect list will not drop down in IE9?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, multi-select

**ISSUE**: Dropdownlist for multiselect wont't drop down after deployed to remote server.

I have it working just fine locally with IE9/Chrome/FF but when I deploy to a remote server it doesn't drop down when clicked (Chrome/FF/IE8 work fine remotely).

I get a javascript;; tool-tip in the browser (left corner) but not sure how to troubleshoot as I'm not a javascript/scripting guru?

Any advice or has anybody ran into this before with jQuery Multiselect?

> http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/multiSelect/demo/
>
> http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/04/jquery-multiselect/